Installing Coq on Mac Error – "“Coq-Platform~8.18~2023.11” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should eject the disk image."
I'm trying to install Coq on my computer (MacBook Pro with M2 chip).
It downloads fine from the official platform page on GitHub, but fails with the following message when I attempt to run it.
"-Platform~8.18~2023.11” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should eject the disk image."
and on occasion
-Platform~8.18~2023.11” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move the disk image to the trash".
Does anybody have any experience or ideas with this?
I downloaded the software from its GitHub page (linked), moved it to my 'Applications' folder and attempted to run it by clicking on it.

Perhaps it is better to ask the developers on github than here if it is a problem with the file.  Note you should control-click it and choose Open (with control pressed) the first time you run it to tell MacOS that you trust the downloaded file. But that is not the issue here, as that would give another error message.
